# Unadjustable soldering iron temperature varies

Tags: soldering

I am currently working on an R&D project. In some parts of the project I need to use solder. I use a soldering iron as a tool for heating, not for soldering components.

My problem is that I'm using a 60 W soldering iron with no temperature control. When I switch on the soldering iron after 20 minutes I check the temperature and it is 300°C but in 23 minutes to 26 minutes the temperature goes down to 280°C, and the temperature rises after 27 minutes.

What causes the soldering iron temperature to rise and fall?

Comment: Ah, you need a soldering station which can set and display temperature.  My cheapy station 
https://www.robotshop.com/media/catalog/product/cache/image/1350x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/e/l/elenco-sl-30-temperature-controller-soldering-station_1.jpg is about US$50 and I found it good for hobbyist work.  For R&D, you might consider a good brand such as W*****.

Comment: I use a solder iron as a tool for heating ,not using soldering iron to soldering the components.

Comment: @muhammadFirdaus What do you mean with "heating"? If you wish to heat a metal surface to a certain specific temperature you should probably use an oven instead.

Comment: @muhammadFirdaus:  What model of soldering iron do you have?

Comment: @JRE https://amtechdiy.com/wp-content/uploads/S17251.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite likely there is simple two-step temperature control, most likely a thermostat that turns power on and off. (You might hear it click from time to time.) In such a system the temperature varies around the setpoint by some amount, depending on time constants, hysteresis and so on. So what you see is not at all unusual.

Comment: I've already try to use the thermostat but the problem in here is the design of the original product cannot fit in it. So my solution right now is use the timer delay relay to stop the current because my load uses solder and serves to heat the load to a certain temperature. That why im asking for the causing of the loses heat in the solder.

Comment: I mean your soldering iron probably already has a built in thermostat. It would be very unusual for there to be no form of control at all. Perhaps you can post a picture or link to it.

Comment: I use this https://amtechdiy.com/wp-content/uploads/S17251.jpg

Comment: I'd say that probably has a built in thermostat. Otherwise it is just going to heat indefinitely which is neither desirable nor safe.

Answer (score 2):

The temperature will stabilise at the temperature where \$ power in = power lost \$. Power will be lost to ambient air and to whatever you're soldering. Temperature-controlled soldering irons use a temperature sensor to reduce power when the operating temperature is reached and to increase the power when the temperature starts to drop.